# Remove unnecesary namekeys from json response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am working with the response from an API which looks like:

```
res: {
  result: { _text: 'NOK' },
    cod: { _text: 'F09' },
    items: { 
      car: { _text: 'f16' }, 
      plane: { _text: 'f11' }
    }
}
```

This response is annoy to work with, because i have to do result._text

I want to transform the response into something like this:

```
res: {
  result: 'NOK',
    cod: 'F09',
    items: { 
      car: 'f16', 
      plane: 'f11' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this necessary to change?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply obtain all the data as Cypherjac mentioned but if you really want to convert the response can do something like this.

```js
const res = {
    result: { _text: 'NOK' },
  cod: { _text: 'F09' },
  items: { car: { _text: "f16" }, plane: { _text: "f11" }}
  }
  
Object.keys(res).forEach((el) => {
    if (Object.keys(res[el]).length>1){ //or check if el === 'items'
    Object.keys(res[el]).forEach((item) => {
        res[el][item] = Object.values(res[el][item])[0]
    })
  }
  else{
    res[el] = Object.values(res[el])[0]
  }
    
})

console.log(res)

console.log(res.result)
console.log(res.cod)
console.log(res.items.car)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct one if the data is to be converted entirely

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the data being returned by the API?

If not, then this is a more explicit way of accessing the values without having to know the names of keys..

```js
// Assuming data is the fetched response from the api
let data = {
    result: { _text: 'NOK' },
    cod: { _text: 'F09' },
    items: {
        car: { _text: "f16" },
        plane: { _text: "f11" }
    }
}
// This function gets the values of the object you've provided
function getVal(val){return Object.values(val)[0]};
// Object.values returns an array
// So we access the first value since the data has only one key '_text'
console.log(getVal(data.result));
console.log(getVal(data.cod));
console.log(getVal(data.items.car));
console.log(getVal(data.items.plane));
```

This is mostly useful if you are not sure of the name of the key being returned

Comment: The key name will always be "_text"

Comment: Yes, it works for both ways, but this snippet is richer because it doesn't assume and is more flexible